# Comprehensive lists; how to use the acquired information?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, pyautogui

I'm using pyautogui to detect images. In this case, pictures of the numbers 1 - 4. I'm not that familiar with comprehensive lists and was wondering if it is possible to see which image of the four got detected. I want to start process 1 if the picture is one.png, process 2 if the picture is two.png and so forth.

```
number = [pyautogui.locateOnScreen(f'{nr}.png', confidence = 0.95)
                for nr in ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The positions of the items in your list will correspond to the positions of the pictures in the tuple -- i.e. `number[0]` will correspond to `"one.png"`, et cetera.

It might be more convenient to make this a dict instead of a list:

```
number = {
    nr: pyautogui.locateOnScreen(f'{nr}.png', confidence = 0.95)
    for nr in ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')
}
```

The keys will be the `nr` strings (`'one'`, `'two'`, etc) and each value will be the result of `locateOnScreen` associated with that specific key.

Comment: Whats the benefit of using a dict instead of a list?

Comment: How would I start the actions for one of the four numbers if I use a dict?

Comment: `start_action(number["one"])`?  I'm not sure what the code to start an action would look like.  The benefit of using a dict is that you can just look up the detected image by name, or you can iterate over the names and images via `numbers.items()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple use case of python list comprehension.
For example,

```
numbers = [i for num in (1,2,3,4)] 
print(numbers)
```

will give output

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

In your case, instead of simply storing `i`(as shown above) in the final list, the output of `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` function for each `nr` is stored in
the number variable.